# Swift Problems understanding the result of Calendar.dateComponents

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

in my app I have a list of contacts including the contacts birthday. 
Now I want to see which of my contacts have birthday within in the next 7 days. 
I am using a filter on my list to filter and return only thos contacts that match

```
     let timeSpan = 7
     let cal = Calendar.current
     let now = Date()
     var birthDays = contactList.filter { (contact) -> Bool in
        if let birthDate = contact.birthDate {
            let difference = cal.dateComponents([.day,.year], from: birthDate as Date, to: now! )
            print("BD:\(birthDate) : DIFF \(difference.day!)")
            return ((difference.day! <= timeSpan) && difference.day! >= 0)
        }
        return false
    }
```

My hope was so. However the result was weired. So I added that ugly print into my closure in order to see the result of 'difference'

What is odd is that for instance the following:
Today is 2017-08-18 one of my contacts was born on 1987-08-19.
So instead of returning a difference.day of 1 I receive 364. If I swap from: and to: in the dateComponents I receive difference.day of -364.

My expectation was to have a difference.day = 1.

Again in Playground

```
import UIKit
var now = Date()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let s = dateFormatter.date(from: "1987-08-19")

let cal = Calendar.current

let difference = cal.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.day,Calendar.Component.month,Calendar.Component.year], from: s!, to: now )
print("\(difference.day!)") // result is difference.day = 30
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that did not help. Now I receive a difference.day = 29

Comment: Hm, where did the comments go?

Comment: Thank you, both answers work. However I favor @Leo Dabos one. I like the elegance in it :-)

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension to return the number of days from the next birthday as follow:

```
extension Date {
    var year:  Int { return Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self)  }
    var month: Int { return Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self) }
    var day:   Int { return Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self)   }
    var noon: Date { return Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: self)! }
    var daysFromBirthday: Int {
        let nextBirthDate = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: Date().year + (month < Date().month ? 1 : 0), month: month, day: day, hour: 12).date ?? Date.distantFuture
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date().noon, to: nextBirthDate).day ?? 0
    }
}
```

And you can now filter your objects as follow:

```
let timeSpan = 0...7

let birthDays = contactList.filter {
    timeSpan ~= $0.birthDate?.daysFromBirthday ?? -1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was you were checking the difference of the days from the user's birthday but in the app we will need to get the difference between the current date and the birthday during this year. Say in the example that you have said, it's the difference between 2017-08-19(this year's birthday) and 2017-08-18(current date). You could try the code below.

```
var now = Date()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let s = dateFormatter.date(from: "1987-08-19")

let cal = Calendar.current

let currentDateComponentsYear = cal.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day], from: newDate!)

var dateComponents = cal.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day], from: s!)
dateComponents.year = currentDateComponentsYear.year
let currentYearBDay = cal.date(from: dateComponents)
currentDateComponentsYear.month
let difference = cal.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.year,Calendar.Component.month,Calendar.Component.day], from:newDate! , to: currentYearBDay! )
let daysDiffernce:Int?
if dateComponents.month == 1 && currentDateComponentsYear.month == 12 && difference.day! < 0 {
    let range = cal.range(of: .day, in: .month, for: newDate!)!
    let numDays = range.count
    daysDiffernce = difference.day! + numDays

} else {
    daysDiffernce = difference.day
}

print("\(daysDiffernce!)") //result 1
```